# Why did my discord stop working in server chat but still works in private?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, pycord

I've working on my first server bot, I've had it working in my server already and then started doing some more tweaking while interacting with it exclusively in my private chat. When I went back to show my friends what it can do now in the server chat, it wouldn't respond.

```
#Base Bot Code
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import abilities
import global_cmds as cm
from units import *

TOKEN = '{token}'
prefix = "!"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
client.load_extension("game")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await msg.channel.send("this works")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
#My Cog Code
import os
from abilities import *
from random import randint
from discord.ext import commands
import global_cmds as cm
import units
import abilities
from db_manager import *

class Game_Cog(commands.Cog, name="Ruby Palace"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.instances = []

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx):
        print("I got here")
        if not ctx.author.bot:
            var = User_Instance(self.bot, ctx)
            await var.run()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Game_Cog(bot))
```

I Added a print statement to my command node to see if it ever reaches that point and it doesn't. I added an on_message after testing the print statement in my cog, and the on_message does work, it listens, gets the message, and responds as it should. For some reason just the command will not trigger, and it only doesn't trigger in my server, it does trigger in private. What's going on?

p.s. I've checked server permissions and everything checks out and is what it's supposed to be, and I don't have any other bots in the server so there shouldn't be any conflicts.

the on_message() was only for testing purposes, I don't use it in my full bot.

Comment: Try using the decorator @client.listen() instead of @client.event before async def on_message
 . Sometimes using the event for message has blocked the execution of commands for me. 
If that doesn't work, you can also try "await client.wait_until_ready()" and then "await client.process_commands(message)" in the async function on_message

Comment: I remove on_message all together because it's not needed for the actual bot functions. With the on_message gone altogether, the commands still don't work